# Error CS0115: no suitable method found to override in a Xamarin bindings library project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, twilio, xamarin-binding, twilio-programmable-voice

I created a **bindings library project** to be able to run an Android .aar file.
One of the several errors i got was:

```
Error  CS0115  'Call.OnWarning(IDictionary)': no suitable method found to override TwilioBindings  C:\...\TwilioBindings\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Twilio.Voice.Call.cs;
```

And to solve it i verified *api.xml* and saw that the method *onWarning* had a parameter with the type *java.util.HashMap*:

```
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="onWarning" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
    <parameter name="p0" type="java.util.HashMap">
    </parameter>
</method>
```

The class *Call* is extending *InternalCall* which implements *RTCMonitorCommand.Listener* and after i checked the *api.xml* file i notice that the method *onWarning* had the follow definition:

*InternalCall*:

```
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="onWarning" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
    <parameter name="warningDetails" type="java.util.HashMap&lt;java.lang.String, java.lang.Object&gt;">
    </parameter>
</method>
```

*RTCMonitorCommand.Listener*:

```
<method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="onWarning" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
    <parameter name="p0" type="java.util.HashMap&lt;java.lang.String, java.lang.Object&gt;">
    </parameter>
</method>
```

So i came to the conclusion that only the class *Call* had a diferent parameter type.

Therefore i wrote the follow line in *Metadata.xml* to change the parameter type of the method *onWarning* in class *Call*:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.twilio.voice']/class[@name='Call']/method[@name='onWarning' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.util.HashMap']]/parameter[1]" name="type">java.util.HashMap&lt;java.lang.String, java.lang.Object&gt;</attr>
```

The error went away but i'm having some problems using this bindings project and this is the line in *Metadata.xml* that i'm not shure that is right.

Does anyone know if my approach was correct ?

Any help whould be apreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: What problem do you meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having problems when calling a method from this binding library and i thought that was caused by some binding error but then, after searching in the logs i came to the conclusion that the problem was that the library wasn't being able to find a dependency. The dependency project was being referenced by the binding project but somehow the reference wasn't working. So i changed the reference and instead of referencing the package i referenced the package dll and now it functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

For future users that come across this error. I have 2 scenarios that caused this issue for me and the fix for them is below:

### Scenario 1:

*"no suitable method found to override"* received after implementing an interface member via metadata.xml to fix the error *"[className] does not implement interface member [memberName]"*. My [className] is `DefaultTimerBar` and my interface member name is `ITimeBar.SetEnabled(bool)`.

```
  <!--Fixes The following metadata change will resolve "[className] does not implement interface member [memberName]",
  however it will now give the error "DefaultTimeBar.SetEnabled(bool): no suitable method found to override"-->

  <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.mycompany.mypackage']/class[@name='DefaultTimeBar']">
    <method name="setEnabled" return="void" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
      <parameter name="p0" type="boolean"/>
    </method>
  </add-node>

  <!--The fix for this scenario was to change the name of the method from "setEnabled" to "SetEnabled". This resolved both errors-->
  <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.mycompany.mypackage']/class[@name='DefaultTimeBar']">
    <method name="SetEnabled" return="void" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
      <parameter name="p0" type="boolean"/>
    </method>
  </add-node>
```

My suspicion is when the interface member is named as "getX()" or "setX()" the compiler sees this as a get/set property.
In the case above for `setEnabled(bool)`, when the method name attribute is lowercase, the method will be implemented as an `override`. Subsequently yielding the error: *No suitable method found to override*.
When changed to uppercase, it will be implemented as `virtual` correctly. My reasoning is due to the same behavior not occurring when the method name does not begin with get/set in the .aar file.

### Scenario 2:

The error *[className].[methodName]: no suitable method found to override* received without previous metadata transform for the specific method. My method was named `SetFullScreen(bool)` so I assumed it was due to the same issue with the compiler incorrectly seeing this as a getter/setter. My solution was to remove the method, then re-add the method with the leading letter of the name capitalized. I simply copied the method's details from the api.xml file within the binding project directory `obj\Debug\api.xml`.

```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.mycompany.mypackage']/class[@name='VideoPlayerViewExo']/method[@name='setFullScreen' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='boolean']]"/>

  <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.mycompany.mypackage']/class[@name='VideoPlayerViewExo']">
    <method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="SetFullScreen" jni-signature="(Z)V" bridge="false" native="false" return="void" jni-return="V" static="false" synchronized="false" synthetic="false" visibility="public">
      <parameter name="fullscreen" type="boolean" jni-type="Z">
      </parameter>
    </method>
  </add-node>
```